# How to talk to MSP430F through DLT/645 protocol?

Tags: serial-communication

I have the following datasheet that partially talks about the DLT/645 Communication Protocol which is a Chinese protocol for having Serial Communication.

http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa488/slaa488.pdf

There is GUI for such device and can talk to it through a serial port and collect the required data. However, I would like to start from scratch and make my own version of GUI!

I know that first I need to know the command to ask the meter to send its reading at phase 1.

In this document on the page 22, it is said that from the GUI to the meter if I put 0x61 0x00 I will get the phase I reading!

My question is how to use these HEX numbers to get phase 1's readings not on their own gui but on a terminal let's say Hyper terminal or so?

What would you advise me to start this from?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest for you to look at your device's preloaded firmware documentation, or the source code itself.

I am currently evaluating the TI MSP430i2040EVM metering chip, which has it's documented protocol in SLAU587.

For instance, to read the phase 1 meters, the correct hex message for my EVM device is: "68 99 99 99 99 99 99 68 23 02 61 00 EC 16", which is start flag, 6 byte address, start flag, command family code, payload length, 2 byte command code, checksum, close flag.

Comment: Jeff,  Yes that is right. But how can I start in visual studio let's say using VB to get the Voltage of Phase one? I believe that I need to send this code in order to receive the meter's reading! That is why I have nothing shown on the terminal when I hook the meter to the Hyper terminal. I need to open the port and send something. Can you guide me through this please? Any sample code to start with? Thank you!